# What is the difference between PSCredentialUIOptions.Default and PSCredentialUIOptions.ValidateUserNameSyntax?

Tags: powershell

One of the overloads in PowerShell for the `$Host.UI.PromptForCredential` method has an `options` parameter, which is a bitwise combination of `PSCredentialUIOptions` values.

Looking at [MSDN for PSCredentialUIOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.pscredentialuioptions%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I find the enum values include:

> **Default** : Validates the user name, but not its existence or
>   correctness.

and

> **ValidateUserNameSyntax** : Validates the syntax of the user name, but
>   not its existence or correctness.

What exactly do these descriptions mean?

For Default, when it validates the user name, does it mean it just checks the user has entered something, anything, in the User Name field of the PSCredentials dialog?

And for `ValidateUserNameSyntax`, how does it validate the syntax of the user name?  By checking for illegal characters in the entered text?

I've tried Googling for more information but all links just lead back to the MSDN page or the identical TechNet page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only does `ValidateUserNameSyntax` check for illegal characters, but it also validates the format of the username against the `allowedCredentialTypes` you supply to `PromptForCredential()`:

```
$PromptCaption = "Creds plz!"
$PromptMessage = "Please input your domain credentials"

$CredentialType = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredentialTypes]::Domain
$ValidateOption = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredentialUIOptions]::ValidateUserNameSyntax

$Host.UI.PromptForCredential($PromptCaption,$PromptMessage,"","",$CredentialType,$ValidateOption)
```

[image]

Comment: that "examples:" prompt shows up even if the `PSCredentialUIOptions.ValidateUserNameSyntax` is null.

Comment: @Matt Not if you change the credential type